# get volume id for EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to get volume id and i have instance id try that code

```
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
response3 = ec2_client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId='i-0fb28a7b3786adee1', Attribute='blockDeviceMapping')
volumes = response3['VolumeId']
print(volumes)
```

but i have error

```
 "errorMessage": "'VolumeId'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    volumes = response3['VolumeId']\n"
```

the output of response 3 when i print it

```
 {'BlockDeviceMappings':
 [{'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1', 'Ebs': {'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 21, 9, 22, 52, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'DeleteOnTermination': True, 'Status': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-054c95927bb8ed4a9'}}]
, 'InstanceId': 'i-0fb28a7b3786adee1', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '3aa0a65b-a47e-482d-83e6-54279ae15751', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '670', 'date': 'Tue, 03 Dec 2019 14:09:02 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the structure, the `VolumeId` located under `BlockDeviceMappings` which is an array then `Ebs` which is a JSON and then you can get a value.

```
response = ec2_client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId='INSTANCE ID', Attribute='blockDeviceMapping')
print(response["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"])
```

[image]

Comment: could you give me tutorial that i can learn from it how i can get value from dictionary have multiple dictionary and list

Comment: You should learn about JSON and Array.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: Sure no problem, feel free to connect me if you have more issues.